# Vuex (Nuxt.js) не видно стет

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

не могу понять по чему не видно стейт в компоненте.

/store/index.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store =()=> new Vuex.Store({
  state:{
    loginWin:false,
  },
});
export default store;
```

В главном странице мне нужно показывать компонент при loginWin = true

Слой
/layouts/default.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Menu/>
    <nuxt />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Menu from '~/components/Menu.vue';

  export default {
    components: {
      Menu
    },
  }
</script>
```

Страница /page.index.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="index">
     <Login v-if="$store.loginWin"/>
  </div>
</template>
```

Компонент меню /components/Menu.vue

```html
<template>
      <div class="menu">
          <div class="fas fa-bars"></div>
          <ul>
            <li>О проекте</li>
            <li>Тарифы</li>
            <li>Тех. поддержка</li>
            <li class="login">
              <button class="btn btn-success" @click="Login">Войти</button>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      export default {
        data(){
          return {
          }
        },
        methods: {      
          Login(){
            console.log(this.$store.loginWin)
            this.$store.loginWin=true;
          },
        }
      }
    </script>
```

При клике не меняется стейт мало того в консоле пишет undefined словно вообще хранилеще не подгрузилось а this.$store отвечает при этом нормально

Answer (score 0):

ой... все разобрался!
забыл что к сейтам обращение идет через его же обьект

```
$store.state.loginWin
```